# Special Javascript Page Refresh for some visitors

Tags: javascript, random, page-refresh

I'm not a programmer so forgive the newbi-ness...

I've observed an interesting page refresh concept on CMSWire.com.  Basically, they're refreshing the page after 15 minutes using javascript.  However, there's a clever catch.  It seems they're only doing this for about 50% of their visitors.  The method - generate a random number between 1 and 1000 then serve the refresh code for anyone over 500 (or something like that).

I'd love to employ a similar technique but have a clue how to write the code...

Anyone care to give it a whack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution sound really simple to me:

Something like this (embedded in your Javascript) will do the trick:

```
var rnd = Math.random() * 1000;
var timeToReload = 60 * 1000 * 15;
if (rnd > 500) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        location.reload();
    }, timeToReload);
}
```

Cheers,
Florian

Comment: Very cool!  ... just one more newbie question.  If I just stick all that inside of some <script> .... </script> tags is that all it takes?

Comment: Darn.... so obviously that doesn't work.  I just tried this:

<script type="text/javascript">

var rnd = Math.random() * 1000;
var timeToReload = 60 * 1000 * 15;
if (rnd > 500) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        location.reload();
    }, timeToReload);
}

</script>

It seems there needs to be more going on there...

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? I just tried it out again and it works. Did you wait 15 Minuten to be sure it doesn't reload? Set timeToReload to something like 5 seconds (would be 5000, because javascript takes milliseconds here) to check that. Furhermore the simple wrapping with <script>-tags is correct and should work just fine.

Comment: Ah!!  It does work.  Thanks very very much.  Out of curiosity, what does the 60 * 1000 * 15 thing mean?  Is that just math to equal 15 minutes?

Comment: Yeah, it just means 60 000 milliseconds multiplied with 15 minutes. setTimeout needs a value given in milliseconds, therefore times 1000 ;)